# RDP crashes in few seconds with mstsc

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10

I have observed a weird issue with windows 10.

If I use `mstsc` to connect to a Windows 10 VM, I get the error "Remote Desktop Connection has stopped working"

[image]

However, if I initiate rdp from ***Remote Desktop*** app in Windows 10, the connection is perfect.

Has anyone else experienced this? How can this be fixed?